# How to show both image and text in a Picker's popup on Mac Catalyst

Tags: swiftui, mac-catalyst

is there a way to show both an image and text in a Picker's popup on Mac Catalyst, as it works on iOS? Tests were done on Mac 13.6 (both Scaled to Match iPad and Optimized for Mac) and iOS 17.0. Do I have to write a custom picker? Thank you

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker ("", selection: $selection) {
            Label { Text("1") } icon: {
                Image(systemName: "circle").foregroundStyle(.red, .blue)
            }
        }
    }
}

@main
struct TestImagePickerApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

iOS screenshot
[image: iOS screenshot]

Mac Catalyst - Scaled to Match iPad screenshot
[image: Mac Catalyst - Scaled to Match iPad screenshot]

Mac Catalyst - Optimized for Mac screenshot
[image: Mac Catalyst - Optimized for Mac screenshot]

Comment: If an iOS look is what you are looking for you can always switch your target to Mac Catalyst for iPad

Comment: @loremipsum Hi Lorem, I'm not looking for an iOS look, I am trying to create a Picker that has both image and text for each option in it's popup. The screenshot I had posted was for Mac Catalyst Scaled to Match iPa. I just added one for Optimized for Mac. Thank you